# For or While loop to find data and paste it into correct location

Tags: vba, excel

This is probably a simple questions but I have been unable to find the answer. What I'm trying to do is iterate through a column of operator names on one worksheet that appear on another worksheet in the same workbook. For each name I want to trigger a if then statement that pulls data from the original worksheet then pastes that data in the cell next to the operator's name. The problem I'm having is that I don't really know how to set up the loops.  My code is below, but I know that it is a mess because I cannot get the loop variables defind correctly (it gives a compile error "next without for" right now). Any help is greatly appriciated.

```
Sub OperatorScrap()

Dim str_dateMin As String
Dim str_dateMax As String
Dim dateMin As Date
Dim dateMax As Date
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim subTotal As Double
Dim lookupDate As Date
Dim subTotal2
Dim OpRange
Dim Orange As Variant
Dim OpName
Dim ScrapRange
Dim ScrapR As Variant

OpRange = "B32:B" & Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ScrapRange = "C32:C" & Range("C" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row


subTotal = 0
subTotal2 = 0

str_dateMin = InputBox("Input beginning date, mm/dd/yyyy:")
str_dateMax = InputBox("Input end date, mm/dd/yyyy:")
dateMin = CDate(str_dateMin)
dateMax = CDate(str_dateMax)

For ScrapR = 1 To ScrapRange
For Orange = 1 To OpRange
Do While OpRange = "daniel"
OpRange = OpRange + 1
For lRow = 2 To lastRow

lookupDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, "AR").Value
OpName = "Daniel"

If dateMin <= lookupDate And lookupDate <= dateMax And Sheets("sheet1").Cells(lRow, "A").Value
  _=   OpName Then
    subTotal = subTotal + Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, "AV").Value
    subTotal2 = subTotal2 + Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, "N").Value
End If
Next lRow
Next Orange

If subTotal2 <> 0 Then
Sheets("Scrap").Activate
Range("c32").Value = (subTotal) / subTotal2
End If

If subTotal2 = 0 Then
ActiveSheet.Range("B32").EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next ScrapR


subTotal = 0
subTotal2 = 0


Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Your `Next Orange` is inside the `Do While` loop, but the `For Orange` is outside the loop. That's going to cause the compile error you described. Same thing with `Next ScrapR`.  You can't have the `Next` inside a control flow statement like a `Do While` unless the `For...` part is *also* inside the same statement.

Comment: The solution is to either put the `For` inside the loop, or put the `Next` outside the loop. I'm not sure which is "correct" for your needs, but either way should resolve that compile error.

Comment: David, Thank you. Moving the for loops inside the while loop did solve my compilation error. However, now I think there is something wrong with how I'm defining my while loop veriable. The macro runs without error but it doesn't produce a solution.

Comment: If you use common debugging techniques to step through your code line-by-line, you can probably identify the problem with your logic.  Since I don't have your workbook/file, it's difficult for me to really tell you what's wrong, but try this:  you have `Do While OpRange = "daniel"` but a few lines earlier you have defined `OpRange` as a string *address*: `OpRange = "B32:B" &...`, so that Do/Loop will *never* execute.

Comment: Here is a link to some good ways for debugging VBA: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: That is exactly the part that I'm confused about. Being new to VBA and programming in general, I'm not sure how to defind my variable. What I want is for the loop to continue from B32 (the begining of the list of operator names) to the end of the operators names. I had defined Do While OpRange <> "" but that didn't seem to be working. So I put "daniel" in just to see if the program would execute at all (daniel is the first name in my list).

Comment: OK. Well what are you trying to do with the `Do While` loop? That basically means "Don't do any of this UNLESS the condition is True".  You may not even need the `Do While` loop at all.

Comment: What I want to do with the while loop is iterate down through the list of operators names. At each iteration the for loops should execute the comands I've written for collecting the data I want associated with each operater name and paste that date in the blank cell next to the corresponding name. I want this to continue until the loop hits the end of the list of names. That is why I thought the Do While OpRange <> "" would work because it is saying do this until you hit a blank cell correct? Thank you very much for your help and patience.

Comment: Try `Do While Range(OpRange).Value <> ""`.

Comment: It gives me a "type mismatch" error and points to that line of the code.

Comment: I made an answer below which is pretty much guesswork on my part, but I think you can do this with fewer loops and without the Do While, entirely.

Comment: I'm offline until Monday. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Declare your range variables as ranges:

```
Dim OpRange as Range
Dim ScrapRange as Range
Dim i as Long 'Use this as a counter in the loops
```

Assign them thusly:

```
Set OpRange = Range("B32:B" & Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Assign ScrapRange using the `Offset` method: this is one column right of `OpRange`:

```
Set ScrapRange = OpRange.Offset(0,1)
```

Then:

```
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row

subTotal = 0
subTotal2 = 0

str_dateMin = InputBox("Input beginning date, mm/dd/yyyy:")
str_dateMax = InputBox("Input end date, mm/dd/yyyy:")
dateMin = CDate(str_dateMin)
dateMax = CDate(str_dateMax)


'Since OpRange and ScrapRange are same size, you can iterate them in parallel with 
' a counter variable, "i"

For i = 1 To OpRange.Cells.Count

    'You can remove these two lines, just use them to debug
    MsgBox OpRange.Cells(i, 1).Value
    MsgBox ScrapRange.Cells(i, 1).Value

    'I think this is what you need:
    '  sets the OpName based on the currenty "i" cell in the iteration of OpRange
    '  so each iteration of "i" will give a different value based on the OpRange
    OpName = OpRange.Cells(i, 1).Value

    'This iterates another worksheet and does your lookup:
    For lRow = 2 To lastRow

        lookupDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, "AR").Value

        If dateMin <= lookupDate And _
               lookupDate <= dateMax And _
               Sheets("sheet1").Cells(lRow, "A").Value = OpName Then

           subTotal = subTotal + Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, "AV").Value
           subTotal2 = subTotal2 + Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, "N").Value
        End If
    Next lRow


    If subTotal2 <> 0 Then
        Sheets("Scrap").Range("c32").Value = (subTotal) / subTotal2
    End If

    If subTotal2 = 0 Then
        Sheets("Scrap").Range("B32").EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    'Reset your subtotals:
    subTotal = 0
    subTotal2 = 0

Next i
```